# first items is drag and dropping from listboxdrag to listboxdrop, how rearrange items in listboxdrop using drag and drop

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, listboxitem

first items is drag and dropping from listboxdrag to listboxdrop, how rearrange items in listboxdrop using drag and drop

```
ListBox dragSource = null;
private void listboxdrop_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox parent = (ListBox)sender;
            dragSource = parent;
            object data = GetDataFromListBox(dragSource, e.GetPosition(parent));

        if (data != null)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(parent, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
#region GetDataFromListBox(ListBox,Point)
    private static object GetDataFromListBox(ListBox source, Point point)
    {
        UIElement element = source.InputHitTest(point) as UIElement;
        if (element != null)
        {
            object data = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            while (data == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            {
                data = source.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(element);
                if (data == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                {
                    element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;
                }
                if (element == source)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            if (data != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            {
                return data;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    private void listboxdrop_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox parent = (ListBox)sender;
        object data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(string));
        ((IList)dragSource.ItemsSource).Remove(data);
        parent.Items.Add(data);
    }
```

**xmal**

```
<Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="listboxdrag" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListBoxdrag_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,29,0,12" Width="215" 
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
        <ListBox x:Name="listboxdrop" Drop="ListBox_Drop" AllowDrop="True"
            PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListBoxdrop_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"     HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,29,12,12" Width="215" 
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
        <TextBlock Height="21" Text="ListBox One" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                   Margin="12,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <TextBlock Height="21" Text="ListBox Two" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                   Margin="0,2,107,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: please someone help me

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are asking. Can you [edit] your question to try to state exactly what you are trying to do, what you have attempted so far, and what your actual result is compared to your expected result? As it stands now, it looks like you are just asking us to write some code for you, which is not what this site is for.

Comment: Hi Rachel ,i posted my code nd xaml part, in that first i drag and drop content from listboxdrag to listboxdrop , but my problem is i cant able to do drag and drop process in listboxdrop my task is to make reorder the items present in listboxdrop by doing drag and drop. .so only i put both  PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown and drop event in listboxdrop . .im facing problem to do drag and drop in listboxdrop. .i hope i explained my que. .and i posted safficient code. .